# What's the Juxtaposition of the two sections?

Tags: kohen-priest, yom-tov, parashas-emor

In this week's parasha, Emor, we have at the beginning of it talking about what the Kohanim can and can't do. Next, we have later in the same parasha details of the Yomim Tovim. What's the connection: why is the topic of Festivals together with the Halachos of Kohanim Gadolim?

Comment: They aren't juxtaposed. There are laws of valid sacrifices in between.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I know, but why are they within the same parasha?

Comment: So that the division of the Torah into 53 sections is approximately balanced in length

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you very much for the simple answer, I'm looking as to what the common thread between these two section of chumash have in common.

Comment: There's simply no reason to think such a thing exists any more than any other random two pieces of Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is true, but am I not allowed to ask the question. These are the two sections I have asked from.

Comment: You are certainly allowed to ask about any two random passages. I'm just pointing out that they are just two random passages and any indication you may have given that there ought be a specific relationship between specifically them is misplaced